# CQRS Dispatcher Without Service Locator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, cqrs

I am creating a new Asp.Net Core solution based on an existing Asp.Net 4.5 solution.

The current solution uses Microsoft Unity Container and the Infrastructure has references to the Service Locator.

I want to get rid of the Service Locator and avoid referencing specific DI containers in my new Infrastructure.

I'm having an issue coming up with a good way to replace the current Command/Query/Event Dispatcher without any DI container dependencies.

Here is my Dispatcher class

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    private const string HandleMethodName = "Handle";

    public TResponse Request<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query)
    {
        Type queryType = query.GetType();

        // used for when OperationResult<object> was used
        Type operationResultTrueReturnType = typeof(TResponse);
        if (operationResultTrueReturnType == typeof(object))
        {
            operationResultTrueReturnType = queryType.GetInterface(typeof(IQuery<>).Name).GenericTypeArguments[0];
        }

        Type handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), operationResultTrueReturnType);
        return ExecuteHandler<TResponse>(handlerType, query, queryType);
    }

    public OperationResult Submit(ICommand command)
    {
        Type commandType = command.GetType();

        var baseTypeAttribute = (CommandBaseTypeAttribute)commandType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandBaseTypeAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (baseTypeAttribute != null)
            commandType = baseTypeAttribute.BaseType;

        try
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);
            return ExecuteHandler<OperationResult>(handlerType, command, commandType);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            return new OperationResult(OperationResultStatus.Failure, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public OperationResult<TResult> Submit<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
    {
        Type commandType = command.GetType();

        var baseTypeAttribute = (CommandBaseTypeAttribute)commandType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandBaseTypeAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (baseTypeAttribute != null)
            commandType = baseTypeAttribute.BaseType;

        try
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(commandType, typeof(TResult));
            return ExecuteHandler<OperationResult<TResult>>(handlerType, command, commandType);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            return new OperationResult<TResult>(OperationResultStatus.Failure, default(TResult), ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Raise(IDomainEvent domainEvent)
    {
        Type domainEventType = domainEvent.GetType();

        try
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(domainEventType);
            ExecuteHandler(handlerType, domainEvent, domainEventType);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {

        }
    }

    private static void ExecuteHandler(Type handlerType, object argument, Type argumentType)
    {
        object handler = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(handlerType);

        if (handler == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Handler not registered for type " + argumentType.Name);

        try
        {
            MethodInfo handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod(HandleMethodName, new[] { argumentType });
            handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { argument });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                throw ex.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static TReturnValue ExecuteHandler<TReturnValue>(Type handlerType, object argument, Type argumentType)
    {
        object handler = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(handlerType);

        if (handler == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Handler not registered for type " + argumentType.Name);

        try
        {
            MethodInfo handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod(HandleMethodName, new[] { argumentType });
            return (TReturnValue)handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { argument });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                throw ex.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

ExecuteHandler has the ServiceLocator call.

How can I handle this without using it?

Comment: The solution is to make an *infrastructure component* that is part of your composition root where you inject your container (replacing this Dispatcher). See [the QueryProcessor class here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) for an example.

Comment: I like NightOwl888's suggestion. If you want to abstract away the service locator then have the dispatcher explicitly depend on a service provider (IServiceProvider) that will be used to do resolutions.

Comment: Since handlers are basically singletons, you should be able to add constraints on your handler, i.e. `ICommand` as marker interface for commands and the command handlers would then be `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`. Registering your handlers as singletons and then resolving then via `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ICommand>>` and register them in a `IDictionary<Type, ICommandHandler<ICommand>>` for easier access. This way you can also avoid directly using the container and move your dispatcher from "Application layer" to one of the core layers (Service/Domain layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the suggestion provided in the comments. If you want to abstract away the service locator then have the dispatcher explicitly depend on an abstract service provider (like `IServiceProvider`) that will be used to do resolutions.

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher {
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public Dispatcher (IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    //...other code removed for brevity

    private object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        return serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    private void ExecuteHandler(Type handlerType, object argument, Type argumentType) {
        object handler = GetService(handlerType);

        if (handler == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Handler not registered for type " + argumentType.Name);

        try {
            MethodInfo handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod(HandleMethodName, new[] { argumentType });
            handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { argument });
        } catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                throw ex.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }

    private TReturnValue ExecuteHandler<TReturnValue>(Type handlerType, object argument, Type argumentType) {
        object handler = GetService(handlerType);

        if (handler == null)
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Handler not registered for type " + argumentType.Name);

        try {
            MethodInfo handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod(HandleMethodName, new[] { argumentType });
            return (TReturnValue)handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { argument });
        } catch (TargetInvocationException ex) {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                throw ex.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }    
}
```

The dispatcher is now no longer tightly coupled to the service locator anti-pattern and allows for any derived provider to be used. This allows you to avoid referencing specific DI containers.

Comment: Ha, that's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

I added an `IServiceProvider` to the Dispatcher's constructor.

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    private const string HandleMethodName = "Handle";

    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public Dispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public TResponse Request<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query)
    {
        Type queryType = query.GetType();

        // used for when OperationResult<object> was used
        Type operationResultTrueReturnType = typeof(TResponse);
        if (operationResultTrueReturnType == typeof(object))
        {
            operationResultTrueReturnType = queryType.GetInterface(typeof(IQuery<>).Name).GenericTypeArguments[0];
        }

        Type handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), operationResultTrueReturnType);
        return ExecuteHandler<TResponse>(handlerType, query, queryType);
    }

    public OperationResult Submit(ICommand command)
    {
        Type commandType = command.GetType();

        var baseTypeAttribute = (CommandBaseTypeAttribute)commandType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandBaseTypeAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (baseTypeAttribute != null)
            commandType = baseTypeAttribute.BaseType;

        try
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);
            return ExecuteHandler<OperationResult>(handlerType, command, commandType);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            return new OperationResult(OperationResultStatus.Failure, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public OperationResult<TResult> Submit<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
    {
        Type commandType = command.GetType();

        var baseTypeAttribute = (CommandBaseTypeAttribute)commandType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CommandBaseTypeAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (baseTypeAttribute != null)
            commandType = baseTypeAttribute.BaseType;

        try
        {
            Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(commandType, typeof(TResult));
            return ExecuteHandler<OperationResult<TResult>>(handlerType, command, commandType);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            return new OperationResult<TResult>(OperationResultStatus.Failure, default(TResult), ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private TReturnValue ExecuteHandler<TReturnValue>(Type handlerType, object argument, Type argumentType)
    {
        object handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(handlerType);

        if (handler == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Handler not registered for type " + argumentType.Name);

        try
        {
            MethodInfo handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod(HandleMethodName, new[] { argumentType });
            return (TReturnValue)handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { argument });
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                throw ex.InnerException;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, injected it in Startup on the client.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ResolutionDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();

    // Domain Event Handlers
    services.AddTransient<IEventHandler<RequestCreatedEvent>, RequestCreatedHandler>();

    // Domain Event Dispatcher
    services.AddSingleton<IDomainEventDispatcher, DomainEventDispatcher>();

    // Units of Work
    services.AddTransient<IResolutionUnitOfWork, ResolutionUnitOfWork>();

    // Commands and Queries
    services.AddTransient<ICommandHandler<CreateRequestCommand, Guid>, CreateRequestHandler>();

    // Command and Query Dispatcher
    services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher, Dispatcher>();
}
```

Comment: You do not need to build the provider before registering the dispatcher. `services.AddSingleton<IDispatcher, Dispatcher>(serviceProvider => new Dispatcher(serviceProvider));`

Comment: @Nkosi, Thanks, I removed that and updated the post.